# Where Should IScrollInfo be Implemented: View or ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I need to implement the IScrollInfo interface, which is a beast from what I have read.  But I am struggling with where it should be implemented.

I think it should be in the View because there's a reference to Visual in the [MakeVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.iscrollinfo.makevisible.aspx) method.  In addition, the ScrollViewer will look for the IScrollInfo interface when you set the CanContentScroll="True". This means that the Custom Panel that arranges my objects will need to inherit the ViewModel or wrap the ViewModel in the view by calling the VM's implementation.

So am I wrong, is it supposed to be in the ViewModel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see [IScrollInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.iscrollinfo.aspx) as pure View.  It represents a "scrollable region" - which has no meaning outside of a particular View.  There is no business logic involved in a "scrollable region", and, as such, it should be kept out of the ViewModel entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You implement IScrollInfo on a custom Panel. As such it is view specific. There is a twist however. Because of the lookless model for WPF controls, the control itself is a viewmodel of sorts.